# In C#, which is faster: 32-bit or 64-bit build?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can compiling my application for 64-bit make it faster or better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498369/how-can-compiling-my-application-for-64-bit-make-it-faster-or-better)

I'm curious: in C#, whats the speed difference between compiling my app in 32-bit vs. 64-bit, assuming that I never have to access more than 3GB of RAM?

Comment: Since the processor handles 64 bit instructions, it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether or not you're working on 64 bit structures (e.g. long).

Also, don't forget that 64 bit apps take up more space since all of the pointers are now double the size; so if you don't need the extra memory and you're not performing a lot of operations on 64 bit operands, 32 might be more efficient.