# C# program works faster on slower PC and vice versa

Tags: c#, performance, execution, multiplatform

I have an OCR program, written with **C#** (WinForms app). So it's **main purpose is to crop, modify, compare, ocr images**.. no more or less. When I run this program on slower machine - I'm getting better results!

**My main machine (stationary PC):**

- Windows 7 X64
- AMD64 5000+ X2 processor
- Samsung HD502IJ 500GB 7200 RPM 16MB Cache SATA hard drive
- 4GB of DDR2 RAM
- 9600GT GF video card

**notebook's config (benq joybook P52)**

- OS: WinXP x86 SP3
- slower AMD turion 64 X2 1.6Ghz
- slower 80 GB 5400RPM sata drive
- 4x less ram: just 1 GB of DDR2 266Hz
- 100x slower graphics: integrated ATI X1600 (**I don't think that graphic card really matters in this test**)
- I can hardly even surf the net with 8 chrome tabs opened

Can you guess what's faster?

- Win7 execution time: 600-700+ms
- WinXP exec. time: 450-500ms

So the question is - **how will you explain this abnormal performance? Is it possible to increase performace on my main PC?**

P.S.: I know it's hard to say without looking at the code.. sorry about that

Comment: Are you running the same binary on both machines, or are you recompiling for the x64 environment?

Comment: I would guess OS is the biggest factor here.

Comment: How you're measuring execution time, using Stopwatch class?

Comment: Use *science* to solve your problem, rather than *asking random people on the internet to guess*. Get a profiler, run the profiler on both machines, compare the profile runs to each other, and then you'll know.

Comment: I'm doing measure using both: stopwatch and getendtime -startTime =Elapsed. Results are +- the same. Now, regarding x64 compiler. I have this strange problem - when I compile the app as x64 - nothing happens, so I thought that app is failing so I used x86 compiler. However, I've just noticed - even though x64 app isn't launched - I can still find an *exe in Debug folder. The resulting performance is much better: up to 380ms!

Comment: Now, Eric, in VSPro I don't have a profiler and I've never used one before.. I was planning to get one at the ending phase of my project.

Comment: @Alex, there are several .Net profiles that offer free trial. You might want to try one of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OCR is non-trivial code.  The most logical first step is to measure!  Profile the performance against the exact same test data in both environments.  That should give you an idea of which pieces of code are taking the longest on the "faster" machine.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information it's hard to say, but **IF** you're running code compiled for x64 on your stationary PC, you could be seeing a problem I've had on a client site. 64-bit code uses larger numbers, so may fill up the processor cache quicker, meaning your code runs slower. Here is a previously answered question that deals with the same issue: [How can compiling my application for 64-bit make it faster or better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498369/how-can-compiling-my-application-for-64-bit-make-it-faster-or-better)

Answer (score 0):

I would say profile both (I use jetbrains) and you may find a hotspot on the faster machine that you were not expecting.

Also I would say OS is a big difference, perhaps get a hold of a usb bootable mini XP, 200-300mb download. And run the code on the good machine in that.

Also the same could be tested with 2 VM's just create one VM with XP and one with windows 7 and see if there is a difference on the same hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Is your application multi-threaded? I read this a little while ago, maybe it doesn't apply for your situation, but very interesting nonetheless.

Basically, the processor type combined with amount of cores and the memory model of your application can have a lot to say.

http://igoro.com/archive/volatile-keyword-in-c-memory-model-explained/

Excerpt:

> On some processors, not only must the compiler avoid certain optimizations on volatile reads and writes, it also has to use special instructions. On a multi-core machine, different cores have different caches. The processors may not bother to keep those caches coherent by default, and special instructions may be needed to flush and refresh the caches.
>
> The mainstream x86 and x64 processors implement a strong memory model where memory access is effectively volatile. So, a volatile field forces the compiler to avoid some high-level optimizations like hoisting a read out of a loop, but otherwise results in the same assembly code as a non-volatile read.
>
> The Itanium processor implements a weaker memory model. To target Itanium, the JIT compiler has to use special instructions for volatile memory accesses: LD.ACQ and ST.REL, instead of LD and ST. Instruction LD.ACQ effectively says, “refresh my cache and then read a value” and ST.REL says, “write a value to my cache and then flush the cache to main memory”. LD and ST on the other hand may just access the processor’s cache, which is not visible to other processors.