# Leveraging 64 bit architecture effectively when porting applications

Tags: c#, .net, performance, 64-bit

I'm considering porting a processor intensive 32 bit .NET 4 (C#) console application to 64 bit. It is a parallelized number crunching algorithm that runs for about five hours.

I know a bit about performance benefits but not sure how to change the code to take full advantage of 64 bit architecture. For example should I consider changing all Int32 types to Int64 etc.?

Where could I find some comprehensive resources to learn about optimization considerations when porting to x64? Searching around has come up mostly with general information about the x64 architecture.

Comment: x64 doesn't magically make your program faster. You get new instructions(such as 64bit arithmetic), and if those fit what you're doing you can get a big speedup, if they don't fit you get nothing.

Comment: Are you certain the process isn't already running as 64bit already? Look at the task manager when it runs on a 64bit machine. If it does not have a *32 after the process name, it is running as 64bit.

Comment: How do you compile your application? Change to `AnyCPU` under project settings and it will automagically run as 64bit on 64bit OSes

Comment: I was compiling with x86 initially and recently switched to x64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's little hope that your hard work will pay off.  An x64 core ticks at the same pace as an x86 core, clock speeds are the same and constrained by the physics of silicon.  One clear advantage an x64 core has is that it can whip 64-bits around at the same time, double the amount of an x86 core.  But in practice there are few real world problems that actually have a need for that range.  Most integer problems work just fine with a range of +/- two billion.  It is easy to tell from your code, if you have a lot of *long* instead of *int* variables in your inner-most loops then you'll be ahead.

A significant *disadvantage* of a x64 core is that it consumes the available cache a lot quicker.  That too is constrained by silicon, there's only so much memory they can fit on a chip.  Any pointer is double the size, 8 bytes instead of 4 bytes in 32-bit mode.  Pointers are used for any object reference.  Cache is a *very* big deal on modern cores, the memory bus is glacially slow compared to the speed of the core.  This disadvantage is balanced somewhat by x64 having a 8 more cpu registers (r8 through r15).

The net effect is that 32-bit code usually executes a bit *faster* than 64-bit code.  You only get a benefit from 64-bit code when your program is bogged down by having to cram the data it processes in a 2 gigabyte address space.  In other words, having to use files or memory-mapped files to avoid running out of memory.  If your app is compute constrained, as suggested in your question, it is very unlikely you'll be ahead.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense, although disappointing. Looks like I'll have to explore other alternatives such as offloading to GPU, creating a custom implementation of BigInteger, etc. to get the significant performance increase I am hoping for.

Comment: A custom implementation of `BigInteger` using unmanaged code could give a pretty large performance boost. For example I know no way to take advantage of 64 bit multiplication instructions using C#.

Answer (score 0):

For pure .NET Code it seems you can't optimize yourself.
Compile to any cpu and the IL compiler will optimize to the x64 for things like extra memory space and a couple of registers more.

See [How can compiling my application for 64-bit make it faster or better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498369/how-can-compiling-my-application-for-64-bit-make-it-faster-or-better?rq=1) for similar discussion

Answer (score 0):

Changing 32bit to 64bit types in itself doesn't help. 32bit operations are all as fast or faster than 64bit operations on x64. What's different is that 64bit operations are faster than in 32bit mode. So for example if you use an array of int32's and you can also use an array of int64's *that's half as long*, it's likely to help.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention whether your application is also memory intensive. However, 
be aware that when making this transition, your applications memory footprint is expected to grow significantly. Since all the reference type pointers are now taking twice the space. In other words, although you have an effectively infinite address space, effective memory utilization is still limited by RAM.

Comment: No, the application is not memory-intensive at all actually.